# Ubuntu 16.04 disconnecting from ethernet

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, internet, vpn, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and recently I get disconnected from the internet (ethernet) a couple of times within an hour. I had my ISP to check my router but they did not find any issues. It happens both on windows and ubuntu so I started monitoring what happens exactly when I get disconnected and I found one thing. Before I get disconnected from the internet `ifconfig` is showing IPv4 address:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:b7:c0:58  
          inet addr:192.168.0.52  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1fbd:36b1:32e6:e918/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30869 (30.8 KB)  TX bytes:26256 (26.2 KB)
```

and after I get disconnected I have no IPv4 address.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:b7:c0:58  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1fbd:36b1:32e6:e918/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30869 (30.8 KB)  TX bytes:26256 (26.2 KB)
```

The logs say just this:

```
Oct  9 23:37:29 Home acvpnagent[3433]: A network interface has gone down.
```

So in `ifconfig` I see that the network interface is not down because `eth0` interface is showing so it's just I don't have the IP anymore. What might be the reason for this? Is there a way to fix it? Is it my NIC or network driver?

#### Update

It's just happened again and this time I unplugged the cable and plugged it back in and the IP came back up.

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: @mchid Yes, I am. When I get disconnected I don't have my VPN connected.

Comment: Okay, that changes things. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Since you are using a VPN:

First, go into your NetworkManager settings and under the VPN settings for your network, in the "identity" section, open "advanced".

Then, untick "disable dead peer detection".

[SOURCE](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-301225.html)

---

original answer to help people with a similar issue:

This looks like a problem with DHCP and there are a couple of things you can do to work around this problem. Also, since you have the same problem on Windows and Ubuntu, it is most likely a problem with your router but it may just be designed that way so according to your ISP, there technically is no "problem" with the router because it is functioning the way that it is designed. It could be some power saving feature on your computers and/or router or it could be something else that is causing a problem with DHCP.

**To work around this problem you can set your local IP to a static IP** in NetworkManager and also set the static IP for your computer in your router settings so that there is no DHCP lease to negotiate.

---

1. Click on the network manager icon on your desktop and then click "Edit Connections"
2. Double click on the connection (like, wired connection or whatever it is)
3. Click on the "IPV4 Settings"  <kbd>TAB</kbd>
4. Click on the dropdown menu for "Method" and select "Manual"
5. Under "Addresses", click "Add"

*Now, here you have to do one at a time and use your <kbd>TAB</kbd> in between each one.*

6. For "Address" type the current local IP address: 192.168.0.52 and then press the  <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to fill in the netmask
7. For "Netmask" type 255.255.255.0 and then press the  <kbd>TAB</kbd> key
8. For "Gateway" use 192.168.1.1 and then press  <kbd>TAB</kbd>

I am assuming your router uses 192.168.0.1 but it may be something else. Many cisco and linksys routers use 192.168.1.1 for their default internal address. Other common router IP addresses for gateway are: 192.168.0.1;  192.168.10.2; 192.168.1.254; 192.168.1.1.

*The gateway is usually the same IP you use to connect to the router to change the settings.*

9. Next, this step is optional. Click in the box for DNS servers and here you can use a public server like 8.8.8.8 or you can sometimes use 192.168.1.1 if your router provides DNS. You could also use an OpenDNS address or check with your ISP.
10. Additionally, in the NetworkManager settings, click on the checkmark box for "require ipv4 addressing".
11. Finally, go into your router settings and set the static IP (192.168.0.52) for your Ubuntu computer.

---

NOTE:

You *must* fill out the "address", "netmask", and "gateway" uninterrupted and this is why I suggest using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in between. If you find that you cannot click the "save" button because it is greyed out, click "cancel" and start over.

You can also try disabling IPV6. Click on the IPV6 tab in NetworkManager and click on the dropdown menu for "method" and select "ignore".

Comment: I don't see 'identity" section anywhere in my Network Manager. Where do I find it?

Comment: @jedi Sorry, that should be under your vpn settings for the network in NetworkManager.

Comment: I am using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client and I don't have this option.

Comment: I've been online for the whole day today without any interruptions so far. I will keep monitoring the issue firther.

Comment: I haven't got disconnected for the past week so it looks like the problem should be in my router.